# How to call a function if the form is submitted succefully with formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik

I am making a react-native app and I'm creating a form using Formik...
I want to call a function if the form is submitted successfully...

Does anyone know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your API call if you called an api and got status code of 200. Just do:

```
onSubmit={async (values) => {
          try {
              // your api call
            if (response.status === 200) {
               // do whatever you want
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        }}
```